# Where are variables stored in Inherited Classes in C++/

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

There have been several questions similar to this but none have answered something I don't understand about inheritance in C++.

I have a simple Parent and Child class the child inherits from the parent. The example here just has a child which is the exact same as the parent but it's value for the integer a is always 0.

`classes.h`

```
#ifndef CLASSES_H
#define CLASSES_H

class Parent {
    private:
        int a,b;

    public:
        Parent():a(0), b(0){};
        Parent(int a, int b):a(a), b(b){};

        int getA(){return this->a;}
        int getB(){return this->b;}

};

class Child: public Parent {
    
    public:
        Child(){Parent();};
        Child(int b){Parent(0, b);};
};


#endif
```

`main.cpp`

```
#include "classes.h"
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main(){
    int a = 2;
    int b = 4;
    Parent parent = Parent(a, b);
    Child child = Child(b);

    cout << "Parent: A=" << parent.getA() << " : B=" << parent.getB() << endl;
    cout << "Child: A=" << child.getA() << " : B=" << child.getB() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

`output`

```
Parent: A=2 : B=4
Child: A=0 : B=0
```

I would have simplistically expected `Child: A=0 : B=4` on the second line but that's not the case.

Looking at other questions I get that if I want Child to be able to access the  private variables directly they need to be protected or public. But I also saw a quote

> A derived class doesn't inherit access to private data members. However, it does inherit a full parent object, which contains any private members which that class declares

What I am trying to understand is how do you "get access" to this  parent object. Should I just assign it to something in the constructor and then rewrite the getter classes to essentiallly redirect to the parent class's getter functions? Because that seems to defeat the purpose of using OOP to capture the parent behaviour. I thought (incorrectly) that the constructor would set up the variables in the child but if that's not the case those variables initialized in the Parent constructor inside the Child constructor must be somewhere right?

I have a similar set up to the one above where a child is a slight modification on the parent  (with some changes to the member functions) and I was able to work it with protected member variables but I am not sure if they are best-practice.

Comment: `Child(int b){Parent(0, b);};` does not do what you think it does.  You probably want to initialize the parent like so `Child(int b) : Parent(0, b) {}`.

Comment: _where a child is a slight modification on the parent_ If the child uses data members of the parent in a different way (modifying them) this may break the code in the parent (as it doesn't "know" the derived child class). I would use this with real care and for exotic use cases only. One solution could be to put the modification of these members into a virtual method which can be overridden by a derived class. (So, you can stick to `private` members in parent which are exposed to the derived class for modification as reference arguments in the virtual method exclusively.)

Comment: Another option is to rethink your design: Maybe, you have two classes with similar but different behavior. These could also be sibling classes derived from the same but abstract parent class. So, the parent class might define some kind of unique interface but the implementation is in the derived child classes exclusively.

Comment: You seem to mix "variable" and "member". `int a`  and `Parent parent` in `main` are variables, but `Parent::a` is a member. They're similar in that both have a type and a name, but the question "where are they stored" has different answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong is

Child(int b){Parent(0, b);};

That constructor creates a parent that is local to the constructor and goes out of scope when the constructor ends. It isn't the new childs Parent (which has been default constructed) its a different, temporary parent.

The Child object does indeed have the parent data, you just haven't set it.

Child(int b):Parent(0, b){}

Would pass b to the base constructor to get the results you expected

"What I am trying to understand is how do you "get access" to this parent object."

If you want access directly to the member data of Parent, you can make that data protected (or public even!), but if your question is more about how you make your getter work to access that data, then it is already working, its just that the data you access isn't the data set in the body of the child constructor.

Maybe it would help prove this to yourself if you put breakpoints on the parent constructors and look at what happens. With your version of the code you should see the parent constructor called twice. First when construction of Child's base Parent happens (via the default constructor in this case) before the body of Childs constructor starts, and then again called from within the body of the Child constructor.

If you make the suggested edit you'll only see the Parent constructor called once.

Comment: I hadn't read the comment before posting this answer - I now see that the same point was made in the first comment.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to understand what private is supposed to achieve.

If the parent class has variables (state) that it explicitly wants to *protect* a derived class from accessing it would declare them private. There is no (easy or readable) round this restriction, it exists specifically to stop derived classes getting direct access to these values. Typically there are protected or public functions that can be used to update or retrieve these private values - this allows the parent class the opportunity to isolate the implementation from the derived classes.

If you want the derived classes to be able to directly interact with the data then declare it protected - that is what protected was intended for.